# Error connecting to database form .NET Core 3.1 API deployed on AWS Lambda

Tags: .net, database, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have deployed a version of a .NET Core API on AWS Lambda but I get this error when I'm trying to access an endpoint who needs access the database.

```
2020-08-11T13:28:38.230+03:00
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]

2020-08-11T13:28:38.230+03:00
An error occurred using the connection to database 'xxx_xxx_xxx' on server 'xx.xx.xx.xx'.

2020-08-11T13:28:38.231+03:00
[Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: An error occurred using the connection to database 'xxx_xxx_xxx' on server 'xx.xx.xx.xx'.
```

The database is a MySQL and is hosted on another server (not in AWS) using cPanel to configure it, and I gave access to the lambda function to use it (adding the public IP of the lambda in the remote access section). I also have an endpoint that uses an external API and this one works (so is not an internet access issue).

Is there any extra configuration I need to do in order to allow the lambda function to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your Lambda network configuration.

The easiest way to debug your Lambda network is to run an EC2 instance in the same subnet of your Lambda, with the same security groups, and try to make the connection from this server to your MySQL database.

You can use telnet to check the basic connectivity or install the Linux MySQL client to see if you can connect to your database using a client.

It can be many issues, here is a list of issues that can occur easily:

- Subnet NACL doesn't allow connections with your database IP.
- Subnet Route Table doesn't have a route to your database IP.
- Security Groups doesn't allow external connections to your database IP + Port.

Aside from these, you can have a network problem in this another server.